# How do you limit the range of records to weeks for each month with Date.new? Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

To clarify, I am building a search that takes three parameters the month/year/week number. I need to know how to return records based on the week number that is passed. For instance, there will be 5 weeks most likely. When I select all three parameters, I should get records back for 7 days or less. As it stands, I have successfully retrieved records by month/year, but now I am introducing the week number as a parameter. How do you pass the week number to the date.new object?

**index.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_tag amb_chart_records_path, :method => :get, :class => "ui form" %>
    <div class="three fields">
     <div class="field">
      <%= select_month(@month.present? @month : nil, {:include_blank => "Select Month"...%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= select_year(@year.present? ? @year : Date.today, {:include_blank => "Select Year"..%>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= select_tag :week, options_for_select([["Week 1", 1], ["Week 2", 2], ["Week 3", 3], ["Week 4", 4], ["Week 5", 5]], params[:week]), class: 'ui dropdown' %>
    </div>    
    </div>
  <div class="field text-center">
    <%= submit_tag("Search", :id => "button", :class => "ui button basic green" %>
  </div>
    <% end %>
```

**amb_chart_records_controller.rb**

```
def index
  if params[:commit] == "Previous" || params[:commit] == "Next"
    now = Date.new(params[:current_year].to_i, params[:current_month].to_i)
    if params[:commit] == "Previous"
      target_date = now - 1.month
    else
      target_date = now + 1.month
    end
  elsif params.has_key?(:select)
    target_date = Date.new(params[:select][:year].to_i, params[:select][:month].to_i, 1)
    week_numb = params[:select][:week].to_i
  else
    target_date = Date.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, 1)
    week_numb = 1
  end
  @year = target_date.year.to_i
  @month = target_date.month.to_i
  @week_numb = target_date.cweek.to_i
  @facilities = Facility.where(is_ambulatory_chart_enabled: true)
  @ambulatory_chart_records = @facilities.includes(:amb_chart_records).order(record_date: :desc).where(:record_date => target_date..target_date + 1.month)
end

def week(year, month, week_number)
  Date.new(year, month, 7 * week_number - 6)
end
```

Comment: Its pretty unclear what you're asking here. Are you asking about getting records for a specific calendar week (like for example week 26) or 1 - 5 weeks from the current date?

Comment: Yes, you give the year/month/week number, and it returns only the week within the given month/year. For instance: If I select Month: June, Year: 2020, Week: Week 1. It returns June 1, 2020 to June 7, 2020 records

Comment: A calendar week is numbered by year. If you want week x of a month you can use `Date.new(year, month).advance(weeks: week)` but that's really something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

To get the beginning of a week in Ruby use the [Date#commercial](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-commercial) method:

```
irb(main):019:0> Date.commercial(2020, 25, 1)
=> Mon, 15 Jun 2020
```

This assumes that weeks begin on a monday. If you need ISO weeks that start on sunday just shift the date a single day with [#change](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-datetime):

```
irb(main):020:0> Date.commercial(2020, 25, 1).change(day: -1)
=> Tue, 30 Jun 2020
```

If you want to query based on week numbers one way to do it is by passing a range between the start and end date:

```
w_start = Date.commercial(year, week_number, 1)
w_end = Date.commercial(year, week_number, 7)
Model.where(some_column: w_start..w_end)
```

As a less polyglot solution you can also use the date functions in the database to extract the week number from date columns:

```
# Postgres
User.where('EXTRACT(week from created_at)::int = ?', 26)
    .where('EXTRACT(year from created_at)::int = ?', 2020)

# MySQL
User.where('WEEK(created_at) = ?', 26)
    .where('YEAR(created_at) = ?', 2020)
```

This is more useful if you are using grouping or aggregation based on the week.

Comment: I will report back after trying your solution.

Comment: The issue I am having here, is that I would would need to know the real number for the week of that point in the year. Its no longer week 1, week 2, week 3, week 4, week 5. So, I cannot use this approach.

Comment: unless i use the cweek in the query you're showing.

Comment: I still have an issue with the week selector. There are only 5 weeks per month. I wouldn't be able to pass the data from the week params to the method itself.

Comment: I tried to explain the difference between calender weeks which is the week of the year (1-52) and what you want which is something completely different. You need to do better at explaining what it is that you're trying to do.

Comment: Week of the month is not really a thing and harder to calculate since a month begins and ends on a arbritary day of the week.

Comment: I don't think it will work unless the week is stored on the record and added to the query itself.